# Disbabled sql server job will still try to run at the original scheduled time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a sql server job, which has been disabled.
But the job continues to attempt to run at the original scheduled time.
I wonder why it keeps doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how the job was disabled?

Answer (score 4):

If the job was disabled by setting the system table directly then it may display in SQL Agent as being disabled, but will actually still run. To disable a job make sure that you either use the SSMS UI or the system stored procedure **sp_update_job**.

Answer (score 2):

Have you done this by updating the sysjobs table manually? If you update the table sysjobs directlu, then you may neglected to update the sysschedules tables to disable the scheduler which will then start the job as per schedule.

If you are disabling it by in t-sql use the sp_update_job procedure in the msdb database.

Answer (score 2):

A disabled job does not run.

- Does it have multiple schedules?
- Have you disabled the schedule?
- Do you have an alert?
- Is it being triggered elsewhere?

You can not update system tables directly in SQL Server 2005+...